# Can't import ParseLoginUI to android studio

Tags: android-studio, parse-platform

I want to import the parse login UI into my project (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android) with android studio.
When i'm selecting the "ParseLoginUI" subfolder the android studio the finish button is disabled and I don't have any option to import the module.
In addition, I can see an error in the AS console:

[image]

There is a way to work this out? Or a workaround to import the module?